# The song stopped to work after adding textview onclick

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

After adding TextView that integrated with play button the song stopped to work so please I need a help with that issue

**What I want is when I Click Play the song should work and the text shown successfully works both of them in the same time** , I hope I explained what I want correctly

The MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.moh;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView mytext;
        Button mybutton;
        mytext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextBoxID);
        mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonID);
        mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mytext.setText("The sound played successfully");
            }
        });
    }


    public void play(View v) {
        if (player == null) {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                }
            });
        }

        player.start();
    }

    public void pause(View v) {
        if (player != null) {
            player.pause();
        }
    }

}
```

The activite_main.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.codifying.multilayered.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:background="#9ac4e9"
        android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="300"
        android:text="Play my favorite sound"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonID"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:onClick="play"
        android:text="Play"
        android:textSize="34sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:onClick="pause"
        android:text="Pause"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextBoxID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you XML layout, you tell the Android Framework, that the method `void play(View)` is the `OnClickListener` for the Button `ButtonID` by writting `android:onClick="play"`. So the method is called when the button is clicked.

But in your `onCreate` method, you assign a new `OnClickListener` to the same button which leads to the problem that `play` is not assigned as an `OnClickListener` anymore.

Move the content of your new `OnClickListener` to the `void play(View)` method:

```
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView mytext;
        Button mybutton;
        mytext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextBoxID);
        mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonID);
    }


    public void play(View v) {
        if (player == null) {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                }
            });
        }

        player.start();
        mytext.setText("The sound played successfully");
    }
...
```